# Is it possible to: increment index by 1 and wrap back to 0 if(index > list.Count) within 1 line of code?

Tags: c#, loops, indexing, syntax

What I'm doing right now:

```
index++;
index %= list.Count;
```

I want to merge them into 1 quick line, something like:

```
++index %= list.Count;
```

But the compiler is not allowing me to.

I would love to know:

1. Is it possible to merge those 2 into 1 quick, easy-to-read line?
2. Explanation why what I'm doing doesn't work, IIRC I used to do that all the time in C/C++

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Or you could avoid modulus arithmetic altogether (although this isn't likely to make a measureable difference in runtime): `if (++index == list.Count) index = 0;`

Answer (score 11):

I'd be *slightly* surprised if the first version worked in C or C++, but then it does surprise me quite often. The reason it doesn't work in C# is that the left-hand side of the `%=` operator has to be a variable, and the expression `++index` isn't classified as a variable - it's a *value*.

I wouldn't call it an "easy to read" line anyway though.  What *is* pretty simple to understand is this:

```
index = (index + 1) % list.Count;
```

No need for a compound assignment operator at all.

Comment: It [works in C++](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jfPcj533a) but [not in C](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MbTrb75rf). It's one of the places where C and C++ differ.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need this:

```
index = (index + 1) % list.Count;
```

This first increments the index, then performs the modulus, always ending up with a valid index for your list.

Regarding your *Is it possible to merge those 2 into 1 quick, easy-to-read line?*, the shortest code isn't always the best readable code. I think the above is explicit enough and not too long. The best option available in my opinion. (This would be the shortest option `index = ++index % list.Count;`, but what is the use of setting index two times?)