# Convert GameObject into the List of Objects made and iterate through

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I trust that there are amazing people here that can solve this problem

I have a List of GameObjects that have been made in my first script;

```
public List<GameObject> _recordinglist = new List<GameObject>();
```

Then a button creates a clone and adds to the _recordinglist

```
      recordedObject = Instantiate(mynewPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
// adding to created list 
_recordinglist.Add(recordedObject);
```

Now in the second Script

I have a working script that

changes the GameObject into other GameObjects. E.g. Turning a Kick into a Clap with the click of different buttons where I would change the Game Object in the Inspector

However

Trying to do

GameObject = List[0];

Gives Errors even though it is initialised

Also I'm not sure how to click/cylce through the list with a button?

Some clear guidance for a relatively beginner coder would be greatly appreciated.

I have already asked in the Unity Forum, but it lead to confusion. I have also emailed directly and the answers aren't detailed enough. I have also checked around and haven't seen exactly what I need.

In other words,

I'm Trying to make

Recording1 = Recording2  or 3, 4 , 5, 6, then start at 1 as I select through.

Instead of just Recording = Recording 2

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Is it possible to: increment index by 1 and wrap back to 0 if(index > list.Count) within 1 line of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459255/is-it-possible-to-increment-index-by-1-and-wrap-back-to-0-ifindex-list-count) ?

Comment: Thanks for this part! I also forgot to say I keep getting this error. Even with your code. I even tried and it still gives a errors "Cannot implicitly convert type 'NatSuite.Examples.HotMic' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'". Do I need to make a copy of the script in this second one to work? –

Comment: Completely unclear what you are doing there ... what is a `NatSuite.Examples.HotMic` ?? .. do you maybe forget to get the `.gameObject` somewhere?

Comment: @derHugo Sorry, the NatSuite script is from a unity plugin script. I basically used it to record and the  list was something I added to create GameObjects with the new Audio. The second script works well with `code _drawObjectPrefab = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("RecordedCube")[0];`  but calling the list.        gives that error. The list is already a game object in the first script(HotMic script) `code public List<GameObject> _recordinglist = new List<GameObject>();`

Comment: `code public void SetRecPrefabType(GameObject[] _recordinglist)
{
_drawObjectPrefab = _recordinglist[0];
}` is the closest I've gotten so far with no errors, but the button Onclick stops showing the function once GameObject[] instead of Gameobject is used

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood, but I think this is what you want:

`GameObject r = _recordings[0]`

(In the question you forgot to give the variable a name)

to iterate through the list:

```
int i = 0;
GameObject go = _recordings[i];
i = (i + 1) % _recordings.Length;
```

The modulus (%) symbol returns the division remainder, so it makes sure `i` would just be set back to 0 when it gets to `_recordings.Length`

Comment: If it's a `List` it would rather be `_recordings.Count` though ;)

Comment: Thanks for this part! I also forgot to say I keep getting this error. Even with your code. I even tried and it still gives a errors "Cannot implicitly convert type 'NatSuite.Examples.HotMic' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'". Do I need to make a copy of the script in this second one to work?

Comment: @SagiZiv Thanks for your answer, I keep getting the error that "Cannot implicitly convert type to'UnityEngine.GameObject'".  the NatSuite script is from a unity plugin script. I basically used it to record and the  list was something I added to create GameObjects with the new Audio. The second script works well with `code _drawObjectPrefab = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("RecordedCube")[0];`  but calling the list.        gives that error. The list is already a game object in the first script(HotMic script) `code public List<GameObject> _recordinglist = new List<GameObject>();`

Comment: `code public void SetRecPrefabType(GameObject[] _recordinglist)
{
_drawObjectPrefab = _recordinglist[0];
}` is the closest I've gotten so far with no errors, but the button Onclick stops showing the function once GameObject[] instead of Gameobject is used